# What are the common options for sharding metrics for different kuberentes components?

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, grafana, prometheus

1) In kubernetes many components (i.e. nodes) have metadata that you want to view by group. Examples:

- monitor CPU usage
- monitor CPU usage *on all machines with GPUs*
- monitor memory usage
- monitor memory usage *on all machines (kubelets) that are labelled with a a particular zone (i.e. 'ASIA-EAST-1')*

And so on : For any metric that is being measured on a node, you might want to view/query it by arbitrary labels or taints that exist on the said node.

In any of these cases, since metrics aren't emitted with labels for all of these data.

*One solution: many prometheus masters*

So far I've thought of one solution: A separate Prometheus master for different logical groups of nodes.  This would allow an administrator to create masters that rollup metrics by an arbitrary label, i.e.

- query cluster for all nodes w/ label = SSD=16GB,
- create a CSV from that list,
- use it as the endpoints for a prometheus master,
- use that as a specific datasource".

2) *Are there any more elegant solutions to this problem?*

The above solution is frought with terror - you are doing alot of work just to "hack" the grafana "data source" concept as a way to shard your metrics up.

3) A few more, crazy ideas... just to help seed a broader conversation on how to shard metrics in kubernetes by hosts...

- Maybe grafana is smart enough to add its own groups, somehow?
- Or can grafana be extended to do the prometheus master polling/rollup itself ?

Comment: I dont really understand the problem, but multiple Prometheus machine does not sounds like a good, scalable answer. you're saying 'since metrics aren't emitted with these metadata' - and i'm not sure why thats the case. We use Telegraf (inside docker) to emit our metrics. it emits whatever we tell to to emit, so I reckon you could do this with kubelets. 

one thing to keep in mind though, is that some metrics do not make sense in a container - like cpu usage, since its a host-level metric and not a container-level metric.

Comment: Its a simple problem of wanting to group queries by node attributes.  One option is to export all the node labels and taints with each node-level-metric, but that might be data-costly.  Another option is to have servers scrape data from different hosts - this is associated with a higher complexity cost .

Comment: thanks! I understand what you're saying. But is it really a problem? are there really so many node-level metrics? I reckon there may be lots of host-level metrics (common to all nodes on that host), but for the most part,  nodes-level metrics are purely from the application you're running - those are probably limited in number (at least in my experience).

Comment: host level metrics are really what im talking about.  CPU used per certain  hardware zones

Comment: Prometheus can do 'joins' in PromQL queries so you could export the node labels, taints and annotations in separate timeseries/with a separate exportes, and join a query-time to bring in the dimension you want to group by.  This is something we do for pod metrics - see https://www.weave.works/aggregating-pod-resource-cpu-memory-usage-arbitrary-labels-prometheus/.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd have one Prometheus per datacenter, to keep things within the same failure domain. You may split that out in future if there's load issues, but for just node exporter stats that's unlikely.

https://www.robustperception.io/scaling-and-federating-prometheus/ describes the general scaling approach.

https://www.robustperception.io/how-to-have-labels-for-machine-roles/ addresses how to aggregate based on things like GPU presence.

I would expect zone to end up as a target label, so no special consideration is required there.